# mail is not sent from IIS7 server, mail code written in php script

Tags: php, iis-7, smtp

I am having IIS7 as my remote desktop, I have kept 5 websites in the server where three websites are made using .net framework and two using PHP,

Mail sending code is written using SMTP authentication in all websites but mail is sent from websites developed using .net framework whereas mail is not sent from websites developed in php.

Mail sending code written in php is below

```
<?php
  $myname=$_POST['myname'];
  $email=$_POST['email'];
  $contact=$_POST['mob'];
  $mandap=$_POST['mandap'];
  $decor=$_POST['decoration'];
  $light=$_POST['light'];
  $photo=$_POST['photo'];
  $catering=$_POST['catering'];
  $travel=$_POST['travel'];
  $hotel=$_POST['hotel'];
  $volun=$_POST['volunteer'];
  $mehndi=$_POST['mehndi'];
  $others=$_POST['others'];
   $service=$mandap.', '.$decor.' ,'.$light.', '.$photo.', '.$catering.', '.$travel.', '.$hotel.' ,'.$volun.', '.$mehndi;

 require_once "Mail.php";

  $from = "$myname <$email>";
  $to = "info@domain.com"; //here i have written my domain name

   $subject = "Contact Details ";
   $body = "Intereted User Name: $myname\n\n Email id: $email\n\nContact No.: $contact\n\n Service needed: $service \n $others";

  $host = "smtp.live.com";
  $port = 25;
  $username = "info@domain.com";
  $password = "password"; // info@domain.com mail password I have written



  $headers = array ('From' => $from, 'To' => $to,'Subject' => $subject);
  $smtp = Mail::factory('smtp',
   array ('host' => $host,'auth' => true, 'username' => $username,
 'password' => $password,'port' => $port));

   $mail = $smtp->send($to, $headers, $body);

   if (PEAR::isError($mail)) {   echo("<p>" . $mail->getMessage() . "</p>");
     } else {
   header('location:index.php');

  }
 ?>
```

In my Remote desktop I configured the same as mentioned in the link below:

```
  [http://hostedenvironments.net/support/support-mail/php-sendmail-on-iis/][1]
```

and

```
  [http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/install-and-configure-php-on-iis/configure-smtp-e-mail-in-iis-7-and-above][2]
```

but still mail is not sent I have spent about 5 hours working on it, well I am a newbie developer have no knowledge about server configuration.

If any one can please help me in this it will be a great help.

If any more information is required I can provide that too.

Comment: Are getting any error??

Comment: no I don't get any error , when form my website contact form I click on submit button the browser gets stuck on the page where I have written code to send mail and no error is displayed. Also when the same website i run in my localhost where XAMPP is intalled mail is sent, there is no error. What Shall I do, I do not know.

Comment: is there any other method to send mail

Comment: hello can anyone help me, i get this error        Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '@' in C:\MY_SERVER\mydemosite.com\mail.php on line 2, i have changed the name of the website